# Windows phone delete object dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone

I am using Data Binding with Converters in my XAML, here it is :

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ConversationMessagesColor}}">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ConversationMessages}}" FontSize="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ConversationMessagesFontSize}}" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ConversationMessagesForeground}}"/>
  </Border>
```

However, in some cases I do need to do not have the "border" property at all. It is not problem to do the logic in some converter or so, but I dont know, which property or method I can use to delete, hide (or disable) Border.

Something like :

```
   <Border Delete="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ConversationMessagesDelete}}" ...
```

---

In some cases I want to hide the Border but still show the TextBlock

Comment: You mean in some cases you want to hide the `Border` but still show the `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways you can do this.

1. Have a `Brush` property in your viewmodel that controls the color of the `Border`. If you don't want to show it, simply set the color to `Transparent`.
2. Replace the `Border` with a `Grid` control. Then put another `Rectangle` (as the background color) inside the `Grid` with the `TextBlock`. Something like this.

   > ```
   > <Grid>
   >     <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundVisual" Fill={StaticResource SomeBrush}/>
   >     <TextBlock ... />
   > </Grid>
   > ```

   And then you just need to control the `Visibility` of the `Rectangle` to hide and show the background color accordingly.

Comment: Ad 1.) controling the color of Border was the first thing I did, but it has one important problem - if the text is too long (and in cases I dont want textbox it is too long), the border cuts the text. Tx for 2, I will try that.

Comment: Aaaah, I had "width" set to 80, that was the problem! Now I changed it to "min-width" and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, if the `TextBlock`'s `Text` is cut, it means that its parent container doesn't have enough space to allocate. So Yeah, since you removed the `Width` constraint, it should work. :)